# Delegates in practical scenario: within class scope Vs within namespace scope

Tags: c#, delegates, scope

What are the advantages-disadvantages of declaring a `Delegate` type within a class scope over declaring it directly within the namespace scope? I mean the following two -

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public delegate string NamespaceScopeDelegate(int x, int y);

    public class ClassX
    {
        //class members
    }
}
```

and,

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public delegate string ClassScopeDelegate(int x, int y);

        //...
        //other class members
    }
}
```

What sort of practical scenario would make me use the later one? I mean where exactly is it appropriate?

**EDIT :**

For the first case whenever I need to instantiate the delegate type, I can do that as -

```
var delegateInstance = new NamespaceScopeDelegate(MethodToPoint);
```

But for the second case, I must use the enclosing type name as -

```
var delegateInstance = new ClassA.ClassScopeDelegate(MethodToPoint);
```

Why would I want to do that? Does the second case provide any sort of encapsulation that I'm no aware of yet? Is there any special scenario that *requires* this sort of accessibility?

Comment: [Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027(v=vs.100).aspx) on nested types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current examples, the only difference is that the second one doesn't clutter your namespace, you need to reference the class it is declared in first. You can use it to make clear that the delegate has a close relationship with the class and it is mostly used by it alone.

The following is also possible (either internal or private):

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        internal/private delegate string ClassScopeDelegate(int x, int y);

        //...
        //other class members
    }
}
```

By making it internal, only the same assembly can access it, and it doesn't clutter your namespace, by making it private, only the class itself may access the delegate declaration.

Comment: Will it be of any use at all if I make the declaration *private*? I mean, it's a *delegate* after all. What's the point declaring it if outer codes cannot refer to it?

Comment: @NerotheZero I can't see much practical use for a nested delegate. In general, I treat nested types as an implementation detail of their owning classes, and hence usually make them `private`. The most useful application I've found so far is if e.g. a public method on `ClassA` returns an interface type, a class nested privately in `ClassA` can implement the interface if the implementation is specific enough to `ClassA` to warrant not making it accessible to outside code.

Comment: @shambulator: I can't recall the exact class names right now, but I think I've seen .NET framework classes to have member delegate types. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @NerotheZero I suspect you're right, but I don't remember the names either. Regardless, @Femaref's answer is pretty much spot on - the only reason to have a *public* nested type is to signal a (very) close association between the two types - *so very* close that most types should be non-nested.

A privately nested delegate doesn't sound very useful at all, and with the introduction of generic `Action` and `Func` delegates, IMO there's even less reason to declare *any* new delegate types, even if they aren't nested at all. Though I realise that's not a very satisfying answer to your question :)

Comment: @shambulator: If an specific implementation of some code is meant *to signal* something, then there must be some reason why it thinks whoever it is signalling (whether the programmer or the client code) should be signaled, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16874/discussion-between-shambulator-and-nero-thezero)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that namespaces are just a nifty naming tool for your classes/delegates.

Take this code, for example:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ClassA
    {
    }
}
```

It produces a class with the name `YourNamespace.ClassA`. There isn't any actual namespace - just a class with dotted name notation.

The same is true for delegates defined inside classes.

What matters is how you wish to organize your code.

Simple as that.

Comment: I think you missed the whole point. The focus here is *NOT* the namespace but the moving of a type declaration from the namespace scope to inside a class scope. And declaring class members are not *a matter of how I wish to organize my code*, it involves `Encapsulation`, accessibility/interface to that member from client code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What sort of practical scenario would make me use the later one?

For delegates, probably none.

From [Nested Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027(v=vs.100).aspx) as already mentioned in a comment:

> **Do not use nested types if the type is likely to be referenced outside of the declaring type.** Declaration of variables and object instantiation for nested types should not be required in common scenarios. **For example, an event-handler delegate that handles an event defined on a class should not be nested in the class.**